# How to import chessboard.js node module into Angular project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, chessboard.js

I'm trying to use chessboard.js as a node module dependency to design chess board UI for one of my Angular projects. As per the documentation instruction

> npm install @chrisoakman/chessboardjs

After that I tried

> import { ChessBoard } from '@chrisoakman/chessboardjs/dist/chessboard-1.0.0';

in my angular component but it doesn't recognize any module with that name.

Upon opening the js file in node_modules, I found that there were no module.exports anywhere and
the whole file contents were written inside an IIFE (function(){....})().

There was on line:1809

> // TODO: do module exports here
>
> window['Chessboard'] = constructor

Which I figured I've to write module.exports by myself

How do I export this module now so that I can import and start using the library?

https://chessboardjs.com/download

P.S : The library works when sourced using script tag on a html page.

Comment: have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-chessboard

Comment: Seems worthy of a bug report...